# Programming trick: not able to modify variable before constructor call

Tags: java, string, constructor

```
public final Class MoneyI implements Money {

     public MoneyI(int a, Currency b) {
     }

     public MoneyI(int a, String b) { 
       b= b.equals("A")?"B":b;
       this(a, Currency.getInstance(b));
     }
}
```

Obviously the second constructor will throw error saying that this should be the first statement in a constructor call.

How can I then modify the string before the call? I cant do `new moneyI(a, Currency.getInstance(b))` because it will create a new instance of MoneyI and not modify in the same call.

Comment: Please take the time to fix the errors in your code.

Comment: You could put that statement inside the parameter for `Currency.getInstance()`. Assignment and all.

Comment: [Factory methods.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply not change the string itself before the constructor call, but send the "correct" value in the call itself (and then, if you still need to modify the parameter, do it):

```
public final Class MoneyI implements Money {

    public MoneyI(int a, Currency b) {
    }

    public MoneyI(int a, String b) { 
        this(a, Currency.getInstance(b.equals("A") ? "B" : b));
        b = b.equals("A") ? "B" : b;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, its sending string b without any modifications ever in getinstance

Answer (score 0):

- Create a static method.
- set the variable and call constructor.

Below check the code

```
public final class MoneyI {
    public MoneyI(int a, Currency b) {

    }

    public static MoneyI moneyImethod(int a, String b) {
        b = b.equals("A") ? "B" : b;
        MoneyI moneyI = new MoneyI(a, Currency.getInstance(b));
        return moneyI;
    }
}
```

I am not sure about this answer. If this is wrong help me to correct it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the singleton pattern. It is a *static factory method*, which is neither necessary not sufficient for singletons.

Comment: Kind of singleton pattern implementation? I am not sure. Ok. I edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a factory method here: you can simply define a static method to modify that parameter:

```
this(a, someMethod(b));
```

where you implement whatever logic to modify `b` in `someMethod`.

The advantage of this over a static factory method is that you can leave the string constructor visible for inheritance, i.e. you can define subclasses which invoke that ctor.